# (present value) How can I multiple 2 range one by one?

Tags: python

I am trying to calculate present value.
And I try to multiply it range by range.
But it will end up with the enswer like this.

```
c = input("cash flow :")
n = int(input("how many years :"))
r = 0.1
cf = c.split()
cf_sum = [0] * n


for i in range(n):
    for n in range(1,n+1):
        cf[i] = float(cf[i])
        PV = cf[i]/((1+r) * n)
        print(PV)
        cf_sum[i] = float(cf_sum[i])
        cf_sum[i] += PV

print(cf_sum)

cash flow :100 200 300
how many years :3
90.9090909090909
45.45454545454545
30.3030303030303
181.8181818181818
90.9090909090909
60.6060606060606
272.7272727272727
136.36363636363635
90.9090909090909
[166.66666666666669, 333.33333333333337, 499.9999999999999]
```

The answer supposed to be like :
PV =100/(1.1) +200/(1.1)^2 +300/(1.1)^3

Also I meet the problem that float and list can't multiply.
I am a python beginner,I would be very grateful if someone can help.

Comment: i don't know what kind of loop youre trying to create but i can tell you're doing it wrong. for example too many variables are named n . value of n is quite unstable maybe you want to rename some of those n. plus if i depends on n, and n itself changes in every loop, then your inner and outer loops should be swapped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cf = input("cash flow :").split()
n = int(input("how many years :"))
r = 0.1
cf_sum = 0

for i in range(n):
    PV = eval(cf[i])/(1+r)**(i+1)
    print(PV)
    cf_sum += PV

print("Net Present Value:",cf_sum)

The result
cash flow :100 200 300

how many years :3
90.9090909090909
165.2892561983471
225.39444027047327
Net Present Value: 481.59278737791124
```

Note: *  for multiplication, **  for power

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!  I don’t know it can be expressed in such a concise way. I appreciate your help very much.

Answer (score 1):

I can see a few issues with the code provided. The first is use of the variable named n. It's first used to hold the number of years, but is then used as the iterating variable in the nested loop and also as a parameter to the range function. This makes it hard to see what n is doing and since n is changing in the nest loop, the number of iterations in the outer loop also changes.

That isn't the only problem. Looking at the overall flow of the program, it looks like the number of years entered is assumed to equal the length of the space delimited list entered at the cash flow prompt. This makes the data a little harder to deal with because you have to split the list and hope what the user entered is valid.

If possible, ask for the number of years first, then ask for the cash flow values in a loop, so you get the value of each cash flow for the year it applies. This allows you to do the exponentiation & division, put the result in a list, then sum the list outside of the loop to end your program.

Comment: Thank you for such practical advice! I will rethink the use of variables and reprogram.